# is there a way to share the composite primary key of a class in a many to one relationship?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two classes TempResult and Result that needs a many-to-one between them. Tempresult has a composite key. Result also needs the all the attributes in the TempResult's composite key except one to be its primary key.

With the @ManyToOne included in TempResult the table structure is all fine if insertable=false and updatable=false is set in the @JoinColumn. But it doesn't allow new entries to be made to the TempResult table. If it is not included there is an error saying repeating columns.

This is how my classes look like.

I tried without setting insertable and updatable to false, but then the columns are getting repeated and there is an error.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tempResult")
public class TempResult {

    @EmbeddedId
    private TempIdentity tempIdentity;

    @Convert(converter = BooleanConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "attendance",nullable = false)
    private boolean attendance;

    @Column(name = "marks")
    private int marks;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "registrationNo",insertable=false,updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name="courseId",insertable=false,updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name="year",insertable=false,updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name="semester",insertable=false,updatable = false)
    })
    Result result;


}
//Composite id class
@Embeddable
public class TempIdentity implements Serializable {

        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "registrationNo")
        private String registrationNo;

        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "courseId")
        private String courseId;

        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "year")
        private int year;

        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "semester")
        private int semester;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "userId",referencedColumnName = "userId")
        User user;
}
```

All the attributes except the userId is needed in the Result table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="result")
public class Result {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ResultIdentity resultIdentity;

    @NotNull
    private int marks;
}
```

//composite key of result table

```
@Embeddable
public class ResultIdentity implements Serializable {

    private String registrationNo;

    private String courseId;

    private int year;

    private int semester;


Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`rms_db`.`#sql-113c_95`, CONSTRAINT `FKa683jvhkm50n035ib6ojqlbu7` FOREIGN KEY (`registration_no`, `course_id`, `year`, `semester`) REFERENCES `result` (`course_id`, `registration_no`, `semeste)
```

I need to insert data to the TempResult Table.But this is preventing. Can someone help please???

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I see is that the class ResultIdentity has not annotation @Column for all the fields. Probably it has to be rewrite in this manner

```
@Embeddable
public class ResultIdentity implements Serializable {

@Table("registration_no")
private String registrationNo;

@Table("course_id")
private String courseId;

@Table("year")
private int year;

@Table("semester")
private int semester;
```

Without the @Table annotation Hibernate can't undertand that these fields are linked to a column. Can you change the code e retest?